# How to center div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I want to set center an outer div alignment. There is some inner div which float is set to left. So outer div is not aligned center
my inner div css is :

```
.inner { 
  float:left; 
  margin:10px; 
  border:1px solid #898989; 
  padding:4px;  
  width:200px; 
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

Comment: You need to show some code in order for others to help

Comment: Glad you pointed that out, rsplak. Otherwise I would have given him the solution straight away...

Comment: Some people just don't appreciate the online communities. I usually fail at paying attention to that before answering. Thanks for pointing that out, rsplak. I'm going to start to look at that more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why is the inner div floated, if it's not needed just center the inner div?

```
.inner { 
  margin:10px auto; 
  border:1px solid #898989; 
  padding:4px;  
  width:200px; 
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

OR if inner is floated so it contains further floats.. then you could add overflow hidden to it

```
.inner { 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:10px auto; 
  border:1px solid #898989; 
  padding:4px;  
  width:200px; 
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

or you could make inner into an inline block- and wrap it in a div with text-align: center;

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"><span>float</span>the inner text</div>
<div class="inner"><span>float</span>the inner text</div>
<div class="inner"><span>float</span>the inner text</div>
<div>

.inner { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin:10px; 
  border:1px solid #898989; 
  padding:4px;  
  width:200px; 
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

.inner {display: inline !ie7;}

span {float: left; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #ffe;}

.outer {text-align: center;}
```

Comment: i floated inner div coz if i dont float inner div than it takes a break and i need to formats div like cells

Comment: so do the last option, and put all your "side by side" or "cells" divs inside the outer div.. give them all a class of inner

Comment: I've updated the last option code with an IE7 workaround and showing multiple cells in the outer div

Comment: feel free to click the tick and or the up arrow - if the answer helped, you get rep too ;)

Comment: ya sure i m new user for this site.

Comment: thanks :)  I'm new too it takes a minute to get used to.. it costs nothing to upvote and you (and me in this case) get rep when you accept! glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Without any more detail in your question all I can suggest is

```
<div style='margin: 0px auto;'>Blah</div>
```

But it does rather depend on what else you have going on.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the horizontal margins to auto:

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">Content</div>
```

But it depends on its float attribute as well. Since I don't know what else you have on your site, I can only recommend for you to try different float attributes (left, right, none).

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div align="center" style="clear:left"> 
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method:

Provided you set a fixed width, 
and the proper DOCTYPE of course, try this

```
    Margin-left:auto;
    Margin-right:auto;
```

Hope it helps.